# systemd-journald.service fails to load during boot

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, boot, systemd-journald

I've accidentally unplugged my NAS and after plugging back it fails to boot because of the following error:

```
[  105.556720] systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
```

I've managed to get access to emergency mode (root had no password defined, now it does) but I can't make the journald service work. I have no idea how to handle the `status=11/SEGV` Segmentation fault error becase I have no idea what could get wrong with memory addressing by unplanned power unpligging?

```
root@syrenka-nas:~# systemctl status systemd-journald | cat
× systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2023-08-29 13:01:31 CEST; 5min ago
TriggeredBy: × systemd-journald.socket
             ○ systemd-journald-audit.socket
             ○ systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
             man:journald.conf(5)
    Process: 343 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journald (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
   Main PID: 343 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
   FD Store: 0 (limit: 4224)
        CPU: 92ms
```

The device is ReadyNAS Duo v2, OS is Debian 12 (upgraded from 11) with some packages from testing branch installed. It's probably also important to note that it was the first reboot since updating packages to Debian 12 (Bookworm) and Debian 13 (Trixie/testing)

```
root@syrenka-nas:~# uname -a
Linux syrenka-nas 6.4.0-2-marvell #1 Debian 6.4.4-3 (2023-08-08) armv5tel GNU/Linux
root@syrenka-nas:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_CODENAME=trixie
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

System services that won't start on boot after the incident:

```
root@syrenka-nas:~# systemctl --failed | cat
  UNIT                          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● systemd-journal-flush.service loaded failed failed Flush Journal to Persistent Storage
● systemd-journald.service      loaded failed failed Journal Service
● systemd-timesyncd.service     loaded failed failed Network Time Synchronization
● systemd-udevd.service         loaded failed failed Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files
● systemd-journald.socket       loaded failed failed Journal Socket
● systemd-udevd-control.socket  loaded failed failed udev Control Socket
● systemd-udevd-kernel.socket   loaded failed failed udev Kernel Socket

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
7 loaded units listed.
```

But the way I undersand it either systemd-journald.service or systemd-journald.socket is the boot failure initiator.

I've tried starting the services manually and clearing `/var/log/journal/` directory in emergency mode and after dozens of hours of googling I've tried changing journald settings:

```
PrivateDevices=no
NoNewPrivileges=no
```

But with no positive results.

Comment: Maybe your journal is corrupted and journald is borking on this

Comment: Sounds valid but how can I actually verify it?